# Zend Framework 2 FormSubmit invoking a controller action

Tags: php, html, zend-framework2

How do I connect a 'submit' button to a controllers action, so when I press the 'Submit' my controller will have a specific action triggered?

MyController:

```
class MyController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function viewAction()
    {
        $form = new MyForm();
        $viewModel = new ViewModel(array('form' => $form));
        $viewModel->setTemplate('myForm');

        return $viewModel;
    }

    public function submitAction()
    {
       // want to trigger this
    }
}
```

MyForm:

```
class MyForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('SubmitForm');
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');


        $this->add(array(   'name'      => 'submit',
                            'type'      => 'Zend\Form\Element\Submit',
                            'attributes' => array('type'    => 'submit',
                                                  'value'   => 'Submit',
                                                  'id'      => 'submitButton'),
        ));
    }

}
```

myForm.phtml:

```
<?php 

$form = $this->form;
$form->prepare();

echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));    // I want pressing this element should route to MyController::submitAction...
echo $this->form()->closeTag();

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$form->setAttribute('action', $url);
```

You can get `$url` by using the Url helpers:

- In a View - `$this->url('my-route');`
- In a Controller - `$this->url()->fromRoute('my-route');`

Comment: if I have two submit buttons, how would I differentiate between them?

Comment: Previously I've had success with using a different value for the 'name' attribute on the submit buttons. I've not used this approach with ZF2 but I would check for a $_POST request then check for my submit buttons by name in the $_POST array.